# CSS Position Absolute NOT ignoring element with no positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a few `<h1>`,`<h2>`,and `<p>` tags inside, then I have a `<div>` below these h1,h2,and p tags inside of this parent `<div>`. I have `position: relative;` on the parent `<div>` and `position:absolute; top:0px;` on the child `<div>`. There is no positioning set in the css for the h1,h2, and p tags. The result I'm getting is, the child `<div>` is positioning to the bottom of the other child elements and not positioning to the very top of the parent div. Is this what is supposed to be happening?

** HTML **

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <h2>sub header</h2>
   <p>paragraph text</p>
   <div id="displayAtTop">test</div>
</div>
```

** CSS **

```
#parentDiv {
   position: relative;
   width: 500px;
   min-height: 300px;
}

#parentDiv h1, #parentDiv h2, #parentDiv p {
   margin-left: 30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
}

#displayAtTop {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 350px;
}
```

I thought absolute positioning was supposed to ignore everything and place it at the very top of the closest parent element with positioning set.

Comment: Just copying and pasting your code into JSFiddle and it seems to be working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/wbL8mwsg/

Comment: Because absolute position set to relative to the parent div, It wont effect the siblings element position...

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/85k8gLo7/

Comment: OK, I got it to work, but I had to call `#parentDiv #displayAtTop { }` for it to work. I don't know why, but it's working.

Answer (score 2):

The code works as expected.

I added a red border to make it easier to see.

I think you might be mistaking the <body> or <html> padding/margin for a problem.

```
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

        #parentDiv {
           position: relative;
           width: 500px;
           min-height: 300px;
           border: 1px solid red;
        }

        #parentDiv h1, #parentDiv h2, #parentDiv p {
           margin-left: 30px;
           margin-top: 30px;
        }

        #displayAtTop {
           position: absolute;
           top: 0px;
           left: 350px;
        }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="parentDiv">
       <h1>Header</h1>
       <h2>sub header</h2>
       <p>paragraph text</p>
       <div id="displayAtTop">test</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/StoneCypher/Lq95hcqe/